# How to bind and create another column for Inactive Users in CSV file

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I would like to get two columns(Active, Inactive) in Excel with proper values.

as of now, I can get only active columns values but I would like to add another column as In-active values, because  of Try Catch, I don`t know how to bind the Inactive column value in CSV

```
foreach($sca in $scaColl)
{
if($sca.Email -ne "")
{ 
try{
$ActiveUser = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $sca.Email | Select-Object -Property DisplayName
New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{Title = $ActiveUser.DisplayName;}| Select-Object Title
}
catch
{
write-host "Error: User Not Found $($sca.Email)" -foregroundcolor Red
            }
     }
}
$Output | Export-Csv -Path D:\CSV\myVar.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Any assistance, please

Comment: I'm assuming, by "Inactive" you mean the user's that could not be found on Azure AD. Is that right?

Comment: Right, getting users and that each and every user checking with Azure AD, I can able to log(csv) only active user, but not InActive users, any assistance to bind csv file to create another column for inactive users